# Is it possible to change the admin posts per page view?

Tags: posts, admin, pagination

In the admin panel (backend) when you go to "posts" it shows you a pagination (in my case with 29 posts per page).

Is it possible to change to posts per page number for a specific post type?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean for a custom post type query in the backend or the frontend ?

Comment: I mean the backend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a wordpress core feature on most (all?) list type admin screen, you just go to the "screen options" (right below the admin bar) and change the "number of items per page" setting. This setting is stored per user per screen therefor each user can customize it to whatever works best for him.

IMO this is all you need, and there is no need to do any coding, but if you want to have different default value than 20, you should investigate where the value is saved in the user meta and set it upon plugin activation.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to set to unlimited somehow?

Comment: no, but remeber that it does a DB query and the more items there are the longer it will take to display the page